# Firefox vs Chrome Scaling issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, media-queries, scaling

I have the same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131256/fixing-site-size-in-firefox-vs-chrome-on-large-screens) whereby on higher dpi displays, firefox appears to be scaling my whole site up by 20%. This includes all site elements, not just text.

Is there a way to force firefox to display pixel-pixel accuracy? for example, I have a wrapper set to 800px at wider viewports, however, firefox is ignoring this by increasing it by 20%, which causes scrolling. 
a working copy of the site is [here](http://www.tinywolf.uk)

I have already set viewport and css reset.

The same issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23099849/stop-firefox-dpi-scaling-when-windows-setting-is-at-125) Note that don't want a local fix for this, but something that will work for anyone that views the site.

Thanks.

Comment: have you made/check that the zoom is reset to normal (in the menu on top left of your browser ) ?

Comment: I've solved this temporarily with a firefox specific media query: `code` @-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  html {
     font-size: .85em;
  }
}`code` I'd appreciate a better fix.