# How to adjust the zoom of website at different browser at different screen size?

Tags: html, css

I have deployed a website it's zoom is fine at screen resolution 1920x1080. I want to zoom 80% at screen resolution 1366x768.

I tried to set

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    body {zoom: 80%;}
}
```

It works fine in chrome but not working properly in internet explorer and microsoft edge.

I have used meta tag for viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.6,               maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

I expect the output that at screen resolution 1366x768 the zoom of page is set to 80%. And it should be compatible with all browser.

Comment: Please define "_not working properly_".

Comment: Please select the related tag for your question.

Answer (score 2):

try using `scale`

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 transform:scale(0.8)
 transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for replying but its leaving a blank space on right side of screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Maybe this can help you too https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/